# Application-specific permissions

Tags: permissions

Is there a way to assign different permissions to specific applications in linux?

I.e: I want some applications to be able to write only to a specific directory, and having no permission for all the other dirs.

At first I thought about system users, but I'd like being able to launch these apps from my account, and they are graphical applications so system users wouldn't even work.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to read about apparmor for Ubuntu and selinux for rpm based distros like Centos.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor

http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page

Comment: AppArmor sounds perfectly like what I need! Thanks!